# nUnit + OWIN Startup class - unable to use SetUpFixture and OneTimeSetUp attribute

Tags: nunit, owin

I have created an Unit Test project (I'm using nUnit), and I want to use the OWIN self host & Castle Windsor inside of it.

But the problem is, I can't manage the following code to be initialized before any tests are executed.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(UnitTests.Startup))]
namespace UnitTests
{   
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class Startup
    {
        public static IWindsorContainer _container;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            containerWithControllers = new WindsorContainer();

            //....
            config.DependencyResolver = new CastleResolver(_container);

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that SetUpFixture is created by nunit framework and method marked with OneTimeSetUp can't have any arguments. So your SetUpFixture class should look something like:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class SetUpFixture
{
    public static TestServer _server;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
    }
}
```